# win 8.1 Put in wrong user on login

Tags: windows-8

Brand new computer for my wife and I entered an old Hotmail email of hers whilst setting it up. Is there a way to change that? The User name is right after the lock screen. The computer is hers and ideally I only want one log in. Thank you all so much Richard

Answer (score 2):

Create another user with the right address or

- go to Control Panel -> Settings -> Users
- go to your accout
- click the **Switch to a Local Account** option (it will dissociate your Microsoft account)
- sing out
- sign in
- repeat the steps and click on **Switch to a Microsoft account**
- enter the right hotmail address

Comment: thank you so much..I will give it a whirl when I get home.

Comment: good luck, hope it helps :)